# What would date be called in this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling with trying to get the date to print out when I try and iterate trough the rows.

```
    # daily stock price using pandas data frame
ts = TimeSeries (key=api_key, output_format = "pandas")

    # Date / Open / High / Low / Close / Adjusted Close / Volume / Dividend / Split
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock_ticker, outputsize ='full')

df = pd.DataFrame(data_daily)
```

When I print out the results
[image]

When I try to do

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['date'], row['1. open'])
```

I get this error
[image]

When I try and use 0 , it just prints out the price again

[image]

Comment: I think you need `print (index)`, so use `print(index, row['1. open'])`

Comment: what are you trying to do? looping is generally discouraged in pandas

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael :) That was the answer. Wow I am such a noob with pandas haha

Comment: @Manakin I am just doing a hobby project on the side while I learn python. Only started learning few weeks ago, so still a newb. But this project is trying to create a back testing tool in order to see what is the optimal cash position to have at any time in the stock market based on how the market is performing. 

If interested, I am a newb coder so appreciate any help haha and making this open source on github too

This is sorta a link to a ranting post on the theory I am trying to test https://myfireproject.com/topic/301-portfolio-management-research/?do=findComment&comment=1910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this answer solved

It was provided by @jezrael

> I think you need print (index), so use print(index, row['1. open'])